# How do I get the name of a JsonProperty in JSON.Net?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class like so:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class foo
{
     [JsonProperty("name_in_json")]
     public string Bar { get; set; }
     // etc. 
     public Dictionary<string, bool> ImageFlags { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON is generated from a CSV file originally, each line representing a foo object - it's basically flat, so I need to map certain keys to imageflags.

I tried to write a CustomCreationConverter based on the example [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidHoerster/archive/2011/07/26/json.net-custom-convertersndasha-quick-tour.aspx).

This seems to map the flags fine, but it fails setting normal properties - it looks for 'bar' instead of 'name_in_json'.

How would I go about getting 'name_in_json' value for an object of type foo?

***edit***:

current solution:

```
 var custAttrs = objectType.GetProperties().Select(p =>     p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), true)).ToArray();
 var propNames = objectType.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name.ToLower()).ToArray();
 Dictionary<string, string> objProps = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 for (int i = 0; i < propNames.Length; i++) 
     // not every property has json equivalent...
     if (0 == custAttrs[i].Length)
     {
         continue;
     }

     var attr = custAttrs[i][0] as JsonPropertyAttribute; 
     objProps.Add(attr.PropertyName.ToLower(), propNames[i].ToLower());
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, in the example above you get all property names from type with:

```
var objProps = objectType.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name.ToLower()).ToArray();
```

So you use only actual property name, what youshould do instead is for each property get custom attribute of type `JsonProperty` using [GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) method, and get json property name from it.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old post, but I would like to suggest a slight modification, which I think is cleaner. (Having recently faced the same problem) It uses anonymous types.

```
var pairs = objectType
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(p => new {
        Property = p,
        Attribute = p
            .GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), true)
            .Cast<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault() });

var objProps = pairs
    .Where(p => p.Attribute != null)
    .ToDictionary(
        p => p.Property.Name,
        p => p.Attribute.PropertyName);
```