# Get the name of JsonProperty Attribute using reflection c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with with JsonProperties.

```
public class MyClass {
    [JsonProperty("Editor 1")]
    public string Editor {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to avoid having magic strings in my code. But I need the name of this JSON Property.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var name = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(nameof(MyClass.Editor)).GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>().Name;
```

But that doesn't work..

The goal would be to have

```
name = "Editor 1"
```

But i'm struggling to get this result. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991535/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-jsonproperty-in-json-net

Comment: *Clarify "didn't work" in questions with relevant details*: in some cases this can illustrate issues not thought (or incorrectly thought) to be related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the name of a JsonProperty in JSON.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991535/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-jsonproperty-in-json-net)

Comment: That solution gets all attributes. I'm looking for a specific one.  If that can't be done then I will have to get all and select the one I need. But that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Your code is right up to the point where you try to access a `Name` property. The property is called `PropertyName`. You can create a utility method with that expression, make the property name to a parameter, and you're done.

Comment: But `PropertyName` would return `Editor` not `Editor 1`..

Comment: No, it takes `PropertyName` from `JsonPropertyAttribute`. Try it out!

Comment: Oh it did work! That was what I was looking for, thanks. If you post an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the name of the property you're trying to access on `JsonPropertyAttribute`.  `Name` doesn't exist.  You want `PropertyName` instead.

```cs
var name = typeof(MyClass)
    .GetProperty(nameof(MyClass.Editor))
    .GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
    .PropertyName;
```

And as an added bonus, here's a little helper method that returns `null` if the property doesn't exist or it doesn't have `JsonPropertyAttribute` applied.  Tweak as needed.

```cs
public static string GetJsonPropertyName(Type type, string propertyName)
{
    if (type is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

    return type.GetProperty(propertyName)
        ?.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
        ?.PropertyName;
}
```