# Get Field name with JsonProperty Value

Tags: c#

i have a class defines a field like this

```cs
[JsonProperty("json_field")] // <-- this is my input: json_field
public string JsonField { get; set; } // <-- this is my output: JsonField
```

people usually want to get "json_field" string when they know "JsonField" string, for EG: [Get the name of JsonProperty Attribute using reflection c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57894327/get-the-name-of-jsonproperty-attribute-using-reflection-c-sharp)

but my goal is the opposite. I want to get the string "JsonField" with my input is "json_field"

Is there any solution

```cs
private string GetFieldNameFromJsonPropertyAttribute(string json_field)
{
  // implement here

  return JsonField;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection. Here's an implementation of the `GetFieldNameFromJsonPropertyAttribute` method:

```cs
public string GetFieldNameFromJsonPropertyAttribute(string jsonProperty)
{
    // Get the class type
    Type classType = typeof(YourClass);

    // Get all properties of the class
    var properties = classType.GetProperties();

    // Iterate through the properties to find the matching JsonPropertyAttribute
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var jsonPropertyAttribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();

        if (jsonPropertyAttribute != null && jsonPropertyAttribute.PropertyName == jsonProperty)
        {
            return property.Name;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This method retrieves the class type, gets all its properties, and iterates through them to find the property with the matching `JsonPropertyAttribute` and `PropertyName`. If found, it returns the property name.

This assumes that you have a class with properties decorated with `JsonPropertyAttribute`. If your class structure is different, you might need to adjust it accordingly.